# References numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I'm writing a document with the class `amsbook`. I have several chapters, and inside the sections only (no subsections). I've used

```
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{teo}[corollary]{Théorème}
\newtheorem{lem}[corollary]{Lemme}
```

and so on.

Now, in chapter 1, section 2 I have "2.2 Theorem : ..."
Also, in chapter 2, section 2 I have "2.2. Lemma : ..."
Each of those has its label, and when I quote one of those in some other chapter i only get "see 2.2", so the reader would not know whether I am talking about I.2.2 or II.2.2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace `[section]` by `[chapter]`.

Comment: @Sigur but then the section number will be missing from the counters for the theorem-like structures; from what I understand from the question, this is not desired.

Comment: Not to forget this: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `\p@corollary` (controlling the prefix used in cross-references) and add the Roman representation for the chapter number:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\swapnumbers 
\theoremstyle{theorem} 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section] 
\newtheorem{teo}[corollary]{Théorème} 
\newtheorem{lem}[corollary]{Lemme}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@corollary{\Roman{chapter}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\ref{cortest} and \ref{lemtest}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\begin{corollary}
\label{cortest}
test
\end{corollary}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\ref{cortest}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}
\begin{lem}
\label{lemtest}
test
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new requirement has been made in a comment: to add the chapter number only if the referenced object appears in a different chapter from the one in which `\ref` is used; this can be done with some string manipulation:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\currentchapter{}
\newcommand\thmref{}

\newcommand\Thmref[1]{%
  \renewcommand\currentchapter{\thechapter}
  \StrBefore{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\thmrefbefore]%\thmrefbefore\currentchapter%
  \StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\thmrefbehind]%\thmrefbehind\currentchapter%
  \IfStrEq{\currentchapter}{\thmrefbefore}{\thmrefbehind}{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral 0\thmrefbefore\relax}.\thmrefbehind} 
}

\swapnumbers 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section] 
\newtheorem{teo}[corollary]{Théorème} 
\newtheorem{lem}[corollary]{Lemme}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@corollary{\arabic{chapter}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
Corollary~\Thmref{cortesta} and Lemme~\Thmref{lemtestb}... On the other hand, Corollary~\Thmref{cortestb} and Lemme~\Thmref{lemtesta}...
\begin{corollary}
\label{cortesta}
test
\end{corollary}
\begin{lem}
\label{lemtesta}
test
\end{lem}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}
Corollary~\Thmref{cortesta} and Lemme~\Thmref{lemtestb}... On the other hand, Corollary~\Thmref{cortestb} and Lemme~\Thmref{lemtesta}...
\begin{corollary}
\label{cortestb}
test
\end{corollary}
\begin{lem}
\label{lemtestb}
test
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

The image for chapter one:

[image]

and the image for chapter two:

[image]

This second approach *doesn't* cooperate with `hyperref`.

Comment: Great!What you suggest perfectly works! Would it be possible to intorduce something more : If I am in chapter 1, then Theorem 2.2. should be enough, but if I am refering to it in the other chapters the I.2.2 would be needed.

Comment: @user30238 Yes, this can be done. Please see my updated answer. An approach that is compatible with `hyperref` will require a different approach.

Comment: Rather than hacking `\p@corollary`, use the `fncylab` package and the command `\labelformat{corollary}{\Roman{chapter}.#1}`.  (It does the same thing, also with the option to produce a more general piece of text with the counter value embedded.)